# The menus in my blender doesn't work correctly

Tags: customization

When I click on a menu it doesn't appear or appears after a few seconds. ([Here's an example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3NidrinThu-QmVqNTBhc2dHNlE)).

[image]

Comment: Please do not post link only questions. When you take the video off your google drive this question is 100% useless. Please add a screen shot or 2, and describe it a bit more,

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if my solution is right but it looks like all the menus appearance delays may be caused by the *User Preferences* settings. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to open it, go to *Interface*-->*Menus* and decrease *Top Level* and *Sub Level* values.
[image]
[image]